# Near Explorer backend not running on local (macOS)

Tags: nearprotocol

I have tried to run the backend as the docs instruct:

```
$ docker-compose up -d wamp
```

then

```
$ npm run dev:testnet
```

OS: macOS

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rDMP.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Autobahn package didn't update for some time now and `ws` versions starting from `8.0.0.` [contain breaking changes](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/issues/550).

Please make sure you didn't remove `package-lock.json` from `backend` folder as it contains working `ws` version which is `7.5.6`.

I suggest `rm -r backend/node_modules` then run `npm i`.

You can also verify that file `backend/node_modules/ws/package.json` has version `7.5.6`.